# What is the correct way to import fields with line breaks?

Tags: import

I've noticed that CSV files containing "\n" will import these characters literally. That makes sense for single-line text, but what is the correct way to handle for note fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe if your csv includes a "real" line break (not a backslash and an "n" but the actual line-break character) then it will be imported as such.